# Images of equivalent linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

If we have linear maps $T_1, T_2 :U \rightarrow V$ with matrices $A$ and $B$ respectively and $A$ and $B$ are equivalent matrices, then what can we say about the images $\text{Im} (T_1) $ and $\text{Im}(T_2)$. It seems to me they are basically the same so we can say that they are isomorphic subspaces of $V$ but I can’t see how to write down this isomorphism.

Comment: It's pretty easy to show that the images are isomorphic - think about the rank of these matrices. But I don't see a way of writing down an explicit isomorphism without making some arbitrary choices like "choose a basis of $ \text{Im}(T_1) $" and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what happens if $T_1 \neq T_2$, but for the same $T$ you can construct with 2 different bases of $U$ 2 equivalent matrices whose Image are different. For example $T \in \mathit{L} (P_{1} (\mathbb{R}) ); T(p(x))=p´(x)$. Let $\beta=\{1,x\}$ and  $\beta´ \{1+x,1-x\}$. Since
\begin{equation}
 \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 1 \\
   1 & -1
 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} =
 \begin{pmatrix}
   1/2 & 1/2 \\
   1/2 & -1/2
 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation} And because there $\exists Q \in M_2 (\mathbb{R}), Q= [I]_{\beta´}^{\beta} \backepsilon [T]_{\beta´}=Q^{-1} [T]_{\beta} Q$,
\begin{align}
1+x &= 1\cdot 1 + 1\cdot x \\
1-x &= 1 \cdot 1 + (-1)\cdot x
\end{align}
\begin{equation}
Q=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & -1
   \end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow  Q^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
   1/2 & 1/2 \\
   1/2 & -1/2
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}.
Now,
\begin{align}
T(1) &=0 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot x \\
T(x) &=1 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot x
\end{align}
So
\begin{equation}
[T]_{\beta}=
 \begin{pmatrix}
   0  & 1 \\
   0  & 0
 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
After some algebra you'll find that
\begin{equation}
[T]_{\beta´}=
 \begin{pmatrix} 
 1/2 & -1/2 \\
 1/2 & -1/2
 \end{pmatrix}
=\dfrac{1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Altough the range of both matrices is $1$; the vector that generates the Image of each transformation is not the same: $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \neq \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$, hence their images aren't the same space.